# React Native - Scrollable content with layout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, react-native

I am crating an application that has a lot of content and therefore needs to scroll down in order to see all of the elements.

The issue that I'm having is that when the content goes beyond a certain point, it does not show anymore. I have tried to use scrollview, however this just messes up the layout completely.

```
render() {
    return (
      <Image style={styles.container} source={require('../../images/home.jpg')} scrollEnabled>
          <View style={styles.map}>

              <GoogleStaticMap
              style={styles.map}
              latitude={this.props.property.latt}
              longitude={this.props.property.long}
              zoom={19}
              size={{ width: width, height: 150 }} />
              <View style={styles.business}>
                <Text style={styles.businessName}>{this.props.property.street_address} {this.props.property.postcode}</Text>

                <View style={styles.toolbar}>
                    <Text style={styles.toolbarButton1}>Directions</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Communications.phonecall('0123456789', true)}>
                    <Text style={styles.toolbarButton}>Call</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={styles.toolbarButton}>Email</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.toolbarTitle}>Rate</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.overview}>
                <Text style={styles.heading}>
                  Overview
                </Text>

                <Text style={styles.bodyText}>{this.props.property.overview}</Text>
              </View>

              <View style={styles.overview}>
                <Text style={styles.heading}>
                  Fact file
                </Text>
                <Text>
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags  fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                  sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                  gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                  fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                  sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                  gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                  fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                  sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                  gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                  fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                  sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                  gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                  fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                  sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                  gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                  fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                  sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                  gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                  fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                  sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                  gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                  fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                  sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                  gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                  fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                  sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                  gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                  fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                  sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                  gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                  fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                  sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                  gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                  fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                  sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                  gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags  fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                    sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                    gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                    fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                    sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                    gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                    fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                    sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                    gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                    fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                    sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                    gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                    fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                    sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                    gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                    fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                    sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                    gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                    fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                    sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                    gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                    fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                    sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                    gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                    fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                    sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                    gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                    fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                    sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                    gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                    fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                    sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                    gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                    fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                    sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                    gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                    fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                    sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                    gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                    fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                    sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                    gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                    fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                    sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                    gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                    fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                    sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                    gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags  fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                      sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                      gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                      fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                      sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                      gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                      fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                      sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                      gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                      fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                      sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                      gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                      fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                      sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                      gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                      fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                      sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                      gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                      fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                      sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                      gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                      fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                      sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                      gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                      fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                      sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                      gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                      fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                      sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                      gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                      fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                      sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                      gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                      fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                      sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                      gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                      fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                      sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                      gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                      fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                      sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                      gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                      fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                      sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                      gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                      fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                      sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                      gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags  fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                        fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                        sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                        gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags  fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                          sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                          gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                          fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                          sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                          gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                          fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                          sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                          gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                          fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                          sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                          gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                          fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                          sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                          gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                          fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                          sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                          gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                          fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                          sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                          gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags
                          fagsdgdsagdsagdasgsdgadsagsdag
                          sgasadgdsagdsagdsagdsagdsagd
                          gsdgsdgsdagsaasddsgasdgsadgsdags

                </Text>

                <Text style={styles.bodyText}>{this.props.testing}</Text>
              </View>


              <View style={styles.overview}>
                <Text style={styles.heading}>
                  Opening Hours
                </Text>

                <Text style={styles.bodyText}>Monday &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{this.props.property.opening_hours.monday_open} - {this.props.property.opening_hours.monday_close}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.bodyText}>Tuesday &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {this.props.property.opening_hours.monday_open} - {this.props.property.opening_hours.monday_close}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.bodyText}>Wednesday &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {this.props.property.opening_hours.monday_open} - {this.props.property.opening_hours.monday_close}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.bodyText}>Thursday &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {this.props.property.opening_hours.monday_open} - {this.props.property.opening_hours.monday_close}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.bodyText}>Friday &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{this.props.property.opening_hours.monday_open} - {this.props.property.opening_hours.monday_close}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.bodyText}>Saturday &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {this.props.property.opening_hours.monday_open} - {this.props.property.opening_hours.monday_close}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.bodyText}>Sunday &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {this.props.property.opening_hours.monday_open} - {this.props.property.opening_hours.monday_close}</Text>
              </View>
           </View>
      </Image>

    )
  }
```

Can anyone recommend where I can use `scrollview` to do what I want to do?

For example, if I add `scrollview`:

[image]

Whereas normally, without `scrollview`

[image]

(This is cutting off the content and the map) ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to place the ScrollView just inside the `<View style={styles.map}>` wrapping everything that was inside this view; and change the style of `<View style={styles.map}>` to { flex : 1 }

`<View style={{flex: 1}}>`